# rails: put and interruption in before filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorization, render, before-filter

I want a before filter like "must_have_permission_to_write" that when called if user hasn't permission to write renders a message saying "you can't do that!" and return.

Problem is I'm getting "can only render or redirect once per action" of course...
how can I stop the execution in the before filter?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest answer is add a redirect and return false to your `must_have_permission_to_write` method.

```
def must_have_permission_to_write
  unless current_user.has_permission?(something)
    redirect_to access_denied_path 
    return false
  end
end
```

Then, create an action for access denied somewhere, add the route, and put whatever you want in the template.

Comment: This "and return false" thing does seem a little dangerous to be using as a pattern. If redirect_to returns nil, then nil is returned instead. Putting "return false" on a separate line is probably a better way to approach this.

Comment: Good call, fixed in the answer

Comment: @tadman +1, unfortunately it's an antipattern that has been ingrained into the "Rails way". I would like to see it go away too.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things I noticed about the posts here:

- Calling render or redirect in a before filter WILL cancel the action. There was a point when rails did not do this, but as far as I know, this is automatic now. I can't seem to find a reference to this online, someone please correct me if I am wrong.
- Using "and return" is a great way to cancel the action if you are actually inside the action. In the examples above the methods are defined as a before filter (i.e. seperate methods) calling "and return" at the end of a method, is not that useful.
- I don't think you should be telling someone "you can't do that", thats not a very secure practice. If someone asks for something they dont have permission to, the response should be 404. By responding like that you are giving this "curious" person too much information.

Answer (score -1):

Just add the `and return`, like doing:

```
before_filter :must_have_permission_to_write

def must_have_permission_to_write
  redirect_to login_path and return unless current_user
end
```

Comment: -1 `return` will return nil from the method (not from the action it is called in), which doesn't do anything. You must return `false` from the filter method. Also, see tadman's response to Ben's answer.