# In Ruby, how do restrict methods in my controllers to specific users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Ruby on Rails, is there a standard way of restricting certain methods in the controller to users who have logged in, or users with specific rights?  Let's say for simplicity's sake I have a blog, and I want everyone to be able to access the "list" and "show" methods in my controller, but I only want logged in users to access the "edit","update","create" and other methods.  Do I have to program the logic, or at least a function call into each one of these functions to check for user access rights, or is there a more formal way?

Comment: You should add before_filter to check what you eant and redirect if unauthorized

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [before_filter](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/before_filter).

```
Class blogController
before_filter :authorize, :except => [:list, :show]

def authorize
    #Your code to get a logged in user
    redirect_to blog_path unless user
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This is called a [Before filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487925/rails-put-and-interruption-in-before-filter)

E.g.

```
PostsController < ApplicationController
   before_filter :authenticate_admin!, :only => [:index, :show]
```

Comment: This would force anyone looking at index or show to be an admin.  I think you mean :except instead of :only?

Comment: no, I specifically meant :only, because the author asked to restrict only *specific* controllers. Agreed that my example of disallowing :index and :show makes little sense, though :).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and in particular the [Devise Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/_pages) for some examples for your question.  This will help with logins and authentication.  Also check out [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).  This will assist with authorization.

With Devise you can allow everyone access to the "index" (list) and "show" actions and restrict people to the other actions using the following line at the top of the blog/post controller.

```
 before_filter :authenticate_user! :except=>[:index, :show]
```